# Element toggles visibility when scrolled to top of window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JQuery to hide an element when scrolling down, and have it show when scrolled back up to the top of the screen. The issue I am having is that whenever I scroll to the top of the window, the element shows then immediately hides again.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
    $('.myElement').hide();
  } else {
   $('.myElement').show();
  }
  console.log($(window).scrollTop());
});
```

I logged the scroll position and it looks like it definitely stays at 0 once it scrolls to the top, so not sure quite why this is happening. I even tried using a greater number than 0, such as 10, but the same thing still happens. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I have added some simple html markup as requested that is pretty much the same setup as my actual code;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    .scroll {
        transform: translate3d(0,-100%,0);
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100;">
<div class="block" style="position: relative; width: 100%;
height: 2000px; background-color: red;">
    <div class="headerWrapper" style="position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%;">
        <div class="first" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 200px; background-color: black;"></div>
        <div class="second" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100px; overflow: hidden;">
            <div class="element" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 200px; background-color: blue; transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;"></div>
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
        $('.element').addClass('scroll');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.second').hide();
        },300);
    } else {
        $('.second').show();
        $('.element').removeClass('scroll');
    }
 console.log($(window).scrollTop());
 });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post your html here so we can test?

Comment: See edit @AlexisGarcia

Answer (score 0):

Try adding 'off' before your scroll event listener to remove any previously applied listeners:

```
$(window).off('scroll').on('scroll', function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
    $('.myElement').hide();
  } else {
   $('.myElement').show();
  }
  console.log($(window).scrollTop());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your initial code works fine. Here's a working example. What seems to be the problem?

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
    $('.element').addClass('scroll');
  } else {
    $('.second').show();
    $('.element').removeClass('scroll');
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .scroll {
      transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
      transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="wrapper" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100;">
    <div class="block" style="position: relative; width: 100%;
height: 2000px; background-color: red;">
      <div class="headerWrapper" style="position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%;">
        <div class="first" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 200px; background-color: black;"></div>
        <div class="second" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100px; overflow: hidden;">
          <div class="element" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 200px; background-color: blue; transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Very odd. When I run the code snippet it works fine, but whenever I open it from an actual html file the blue bar wrapper just disappears when I scroll to the top

Comment: @user1391152, may be some other code inside your files is affecting this behavior?

Comment: I tried using the exact same code I posted above in an html file and it still happens